# Seeking algorithm that can re-locate vertices on linestring so that line does not intersect land polygons

Tags: postgis, interpolation, linestring, smoothing, trajectory

I'm currently working with GPS data gathered from boats. The data has low temporal resolution (every 5 minutes) which causes the linestrings that display the boat's trajectory to be jagged. An example is shown below:

[image: vessel trajectory linestring]

As you can see, this interpolated linestring intersects the land, but the points that were used to construct it all lie inside water.

Is there any way I can smooth this line out to avoid land?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing some research I found a potential solution using R's smoothr package. The smoothing spline function creates a smooth line feature that intersects all the original vertices from the input linestring. Here's the code:

```
library(sf)
library(RPostgreSQL)
library(rpostgis)
library(smoothr)

#connection to my postgis database
con <- dbConnect('PostgreSQL', dbname = 'ncfo_data', host = 'localhost', 
                 user = 'postgres', password = '*****')

qry <- "SELECT * FROM route_lines WHERE segment_id IS NOT NULL"
rts = st_read(con, query = qry)

#geom column represents the linestring geometry for my data
l_smooth_spline <- smooth(rts$geom, method = 'spline')
smooth_geom <- st_sf(geom = l_smooth_spline)

#updates the original geometry with the new, smoothed spline geometry
rts$geom <- st_geometry(smooth_geom)
st_write(rts, con, 'route_splines')


dbDisconnect(con)
```

Here's what the results look like:

Before smoothing:

[image: route line before smoothing spline is applied]

After smoothing:

[image: route line after smoothing spline is applied]

Overall it isn't a perfect solution but it's an improvement.